# Firebase error: No firebase app default has been created

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux

I am making a food delivery app using react-native and redux. I want to fetch the data from the firebase store and for that, I have written a function in the **actions**.js, but whenever I run the app it shows the Error

`Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).`

Here is the function which I am using to fetch the data
**action.js**

```
import firebase from "firebase"
export const ProductDetails = (data) => {
  return {
    type: "PRODUCT_ITEMS",
    payload: {
      data,
    },
  };
};

var db = firebase.firestore();
var docRef = db.collection("Products").doc("Items");
export const FetchItems = () => {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    return await docRef
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("Document Data", doc.data());
          dispatch(ProductDetails(doc.data));
        } else {
          console.log("NO such document");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

Here is my **App.js** file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AppStack from "./components/navigation/AppStack";

import firebase from "firebase";
import {Provider} from "redux"
import store from "./store"

import { useDispatch, useSelector, Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";
import AppWrapper from "./AppWrapper";

export default function App() {
  
  const firebaseConfig = {
  };
  if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
  return  (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend creating a separate file `firebase.js` and export Firebase services from there after initialization.

**firebase.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {...};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

Then import these wherever you need them:

```
// App.js for example

import {firestore, auth} from './firebase.js'

//var docRef = firestore.collection("Products").doc("Items");
```

Comment: Thanks, bro this helped me, and I have added a extra line ```if(firebase.apps.length===0){firebase.initializeApp(config)}```

Comment: @AyushKumar yes that's nice to have. I'll update the answer :D

Comment: Is the auth service instance returned by `firebase.auth()` guaranteed to be kept up-to-date? For example, will `auth.currentUser === firebase.auth().currentUser` at all times?

Comment: @Ninjakannon yes, if you need realtime updates then you should use `onAuthStateChanged`

Answer (score 8):

for users with expo(v44) and **firebase(v9)**

**firebaseUtil.js**

```
import { initializeApp, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export { db, auth };
```

**Login.js**

```
import { auth } from "../../util/firebaseUtil";

export default function Login() {

  const onSignUp = () => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

  return (
    ...
  )

}
```

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. I just got past this problem from this answer. Thanks for including the Version of Firebase in the answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

I initially placed the [FIRApp configure]; just before return YES; in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Moving the configure to the start of this method solved it for me.

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ [FIRApp configure];
```

Comment: I tried loads of things over a day or so but this was the one that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I think my error is caused by Webpack chunking(bootstrap). I did import the file with `initializeApp()`. My work around for who has the same problem.

1. Modularize the `initializeApp` in one file(`initFire` for me) and export anything(doesn't have to be `app`)
2. Import & Export before first usage of `getApp()`(methods like `getAuth()` will call it),
3. In this way, after Webpack it will still run first. (ES6 `export {app} from "./initFire"`)

(This answer is grepped from [my own GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/Pablion/Pablion/wiki/Firebase-Learning-Note), not plagiarizing)