# Can't use firebase in React component, because it's not initialized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to initialize firebase in my App.js, so that I can utilize the user's auth state throughout multiple scenes. My Sign In/Sign Out logic is tied to 2 seperate button components that are conditionally rendered in my header.

I'm receiving this error, which leads me to believe that the buttons are using "firebase" before it's init'd.

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app).

**App.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import Header from './components/core/Header';

firebase.initializeApp({...});

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Header />
  </div>
)
```

Is there a way I can initialize firebase to my whole application before the import of Header? Or can I not separate the signIn/Out logic from my App.js?

Comment: Have you tried initializing Firebase in a separate file as in this answer? [Firebase error: No firebase app default has been created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470035/firebase-error-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created)

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yup, this fixed it. Sorry I must have missed that previous question before posting, thank you!