# Correct way for using Firebase SDK in Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

In Expo's official document - [Firebase SDK setup](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#firebase-sdk-setup) it is given that we need to store Firebase SDK. From some other articles I got to know that it should be stored in some javascript file. But now the question is how do I connect it with my App.js file or any app related file.

So for now I have just imported the file in the my App.js file but not using it in other pages. If I don't do this I receive an error saying "Firebase not initialized".

Should I add the SDK code in App.js file itself or is there any proper way to work with this ?

Comment: Have you tried initializing Firebase in a separate file as in this answer? [Firebase error: No firebase app default has been created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470035/firebase-error-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created) ?

Comment: I think I have got the idea. Basically I was importing "auth" and other stuff from Firebase Package into the files where I was using them. Which worked because of singleton design. I'll definitely try the above solution and let you know if it works. Thanks